# Running Fitnesse Tests with maven

Tags: maven, maven-3, junit4, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I created `JUnit`-tests for my Fitnesse testcases:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import fitnesse.junit.FitNesseRunner;
@RunWith(FitNesseRunner.class)
@FitNesseRunner.Suite("mysuite")
@FitNesseRunner.FitnesseDir(".")
@FitNesseRunner.OutputDir("./target/fitnesse-results")
public class RunFitnesseTestMySuite {
}
```

Now I can execute this test like a normal `JUnit`testcase in Eclipse.

However, `maven`completly ignores this test. All my other `JUnit`s are executed by maven but not this particular `Fitnesse` test.

This seems strange to me because `@RunWith` is a normal `JUnit`annotation and so I would expect maven to also run these tests.

Any ideas?

Comment: JUnit `4.12`and the Maven debug logs show no information that would indicate an error or something strange. These tests just seem to not exist for Maven.

Comment: Yes. Maven runs other plain JUnit testcases in the same package.

Comment: I don't have any test methods. But even if I add a dummy method with `fail();` the test does not get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have not configured surefire to run tests with a non-default name. Your test class does not match surefire's defaults and therefore will only be run if you configure the tests to run explicitly. From [surefire documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html):

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test
>   classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> - "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>     filenames that start with "Test".
> - "**/*Test.java" - includes all of
>     its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
> - "**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java
>     filenames that end with "Tests".
> - "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of
>     its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".
>
> If the test classes do not follow any of these naming conventions, then
>   configure Surefire Plugin and specify the tests you want to include.

In your case I expect you want to use something like:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Suite.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```